# psexec throwing username or password is incorrect

Tags: windows, remote-access, psexec

I´m trying to execute a ping on a remote computer with psexec.

```
psexec \\mycomputer -u admin -p admin ping localhost
```

This is the result:

```
Couldn't access mycomputer:
The user name or password is incorrect.
```

When I do the same with the IP address, it works.

```
psexec \\10.0.0.1 -u admin -p admin ping localhost
```

I checked my host file to confirm that there's a line for

```
10.0.0.1 mycomputer
```

Other services, like opening a RD to mycomputer are working, it´s just psexec with naming which is not working.

OS: Windows 8
This user is administrator on the remote machine, and I´m running CMD as admin.

Any suggestion?
Thanks!